# eclipse library bundle - fails to export packages from some libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi

I've created a simple plugin project in eclipse 3.5 that just stores third-party libraries for the use by other bundles in an eclipse RCP application. Worked as expected: I edited the manifest, exported the required packages and added the libraries to the build path (project build path as well as manifest build path).

Some days later I added another jar to that project, did the same steps (exporting a package, adding the library to the build path(s)) but this time I can't import classes from that exported package in other bundles. The package was clearly selectable on the manifest editor but import statements in classes just taunt me with curly red lines. Importing classes from other packages exported by the bundles still works, only classes from the newly added lib remain invisible.

Has anyone has an idea what I might have missed? I'm pretty stuck and have no idea how to convince google to show me the solution to that ugly issue...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check the following:

1. Make sure they are in the Build
   Configuration -> Order and Export
   area, and they are check for export.
2. Make sure you have the packages
   exported in the manifest (PDE Tools
   -> Open Manifest -> Runtime tab)
3. In the same place as above, make
   sure the JAR files are in the
   manifest classpath.
4. (as Al says
   below), make sure the build
   properties has your jars marked for
   exclusion (though this is not likely
   your issue as you are getting errors
   compiling).

If all of this is done (and it's still not working), do a clean build an restart eclipse.  Sometimes the Eclipse gets a little confused about this and a restart helps.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! #1 was a hit. The lib wasn't checkd in the Order and Export area. Guess it happend because I added that library manually and didn't do a 'add to build path' from the context menu. Problem solved :)

Comment: Yeah, I hit that one sometimes, and usually after some frustration finally check that.

Comment: After spending one hour searching for a solution, #1 was a hit. Funny, I wrote dozen of this kind of plug-ins and did not remember this. Was it always a required manual step?

Comment: @Barthelemy - no, as far as I know it's not a manual step, just sometimes it gets off for some reason, so it's good to check it.

Answer (score 1):

Check the build.properties to see if the bin.includes includes your newly added Jar. Without it, it won't be exported by the build process, and thus won't be able to use it in dependent bundles.

Comment: That's not the problem, `bin.includes` includes the lib, even tried sorting and ordering (moved the library to first or last position.. after a while your try even the weirdest things)

Answer (score 0):

if all this still does not help: there is a link item "update the classpath settings" on the Overview page of the manifest editor. Clicking this innocent little thingy finally did the job for me